# ¿Como implementar face-api.js en laravel?

Tags: javascript, laravel, npm

estoy intentando hacer uso de la librería de [face-api.js](https://github.com/justadudewhohacks/face-api.js/), y como soy algo nuevo en laravel estoy un poco perdido, siguiendo la documentación en el repositorio de github ejecute el siguiente comando en mi proyecto:

`npm i face-api.js`

Y hasta el momento parecia estar normal, el problema vino cuando intenté iniciar el proyecto, algo como un `init` que me generará los archivos necesarios, pero para ser sincero, no entendí como iniciarlo, intente importar la librería desde un componente de `vue.js`, con la siguiente linea:

`import faceapi from 'face-api.js';`

No funcionó, al momento de compilar me lanzo el siguiente error:

> WARNING in ./resources/js/components/CameraComponent.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??clonedRuleSet-5[0].rules[0].use[0]!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js??vue-loader-options!./resources/js/components/CameraComponent.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&) 31:23-62
> export 'default' (imported as 'faceapi') was not found in 'face-api.js' (possible exports: AgeGenderNet, BoundingBox, Box, ComposableTask, ComputeAllFaceDescriptorsTask, ComputeFaceDescriptorsTaskBase, ComputeSingleFaceDescriptorTask, DetectAllFaceLandmarksTask, DetectAllFacesTask, DetectFaceLandmarksTaskBase, DetectFacesTaskBase, DetectSingleFaceLandmarksTask, DetectSingleFaceTask, Dimensions, FACE_EXPRESSION_LABELS, FaceDetection, FaceDetectionNet, FaceExpressionNet, FaceExpressions, FaceLandmark68Net, FaceLandmark68TinyNet, FaceLandmarkNet, FaceLandmarks, FaceLandmarks5, FaceLandmarks68, FaceMatch, FaceMatcher, FaceRecognitionNet, Gender, LabeledBox, LabeledFaceDescriptors, Mtcnn, MtcnnOptions, NetInput, NeuralNetwork, ObjectDetection, Point, PredictedBox, Rect, SsdMobilenetv1, SsdMobilenetv1Options, TinyFaceDetector, TinyFaceDetectorOptions, TinyYolov2, TinyYolov2Options,
> TinyYolov2SizeType, allFaces, allFacesMtcnn, allFacesSsdMobilenetv1, allFacesTinyYolov2, awaitMediaLoaded, bufferToImage, computeFaceDescriptor, createCanvas, createCanvasFromMedia, createFaceDetectionNet, createFaceRecognitionNet, createMtcnn, createSsdMobilenetv1, createTinyFaceDetector, createTinyYolov2, detectAllFaces, detectFaceLandmarks, detectFaceLandmarksTiny, detectLandmarks, detectSingleFace, draw, env, euclideanDistance, extendWithAge, extendWithFaceDescriptor, extendWithFaceDetection, extendWithFaceExpressions, extendWithFaceLandmarks, extendWithGender, extractFaceTensors, extractFaces, fetchImage, fetchJson, fetchNetWeights, fetchOrThrow, getContext2dOrThrow, getMediaDimensions, imageTensorToCanvas, imageToSquare, inverseSigmoid, iou, isMediaElement, isMediaLoaded, isWithAge, isWithFaceDetection, isWithFaceExpressions, isWithFaceLandmarks, isWithGender, loadAgeGenderModel, loadFaceDetectionModel, loadFaceExpressionModel, loadFaceLandmarkModel, loadFaceLandmarkTinyModel, loadFaceRecognitionModel, loadMtcnnModel, loadSsdMobilenetv1Model, loadTinyFaceDetectorModel, loadTinyYolov2Model, loadWeightMap, locateFaces, matchDimensions, minBbox, mtcnn, nets, nonMaxSuppression, normalize, padToSquare, predictAgeAndGender, recognizeFaceExpressions,
> resizeResults, resolveInput, shuffleArray, sigmoid, ssdMobilenetv1, tf, tinyFaceDetector, tinyYolov2, toNetInput, utils, validateConfig)

Entendí que la liberia no existe, y no se como iniciarlo, una ayudita por favor.

Comment: Hola @porloscerrosΨ hice lo que me dijiste, y me arrojó el siguiente error
`WARNING in ./node_modules/face-api.js/build/es6/env/createFileSystem.js 5:17-30
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\elias\Documents\PC_IV\Programacion_Computacional_IV\proyecto_final\node_modules\face-api.js\build\es6\env'`

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda @porloscerrosΨ, ya me funciono

Comment: Sí, lo hare, pero en un momento

Answer (score 1):

Solución:

Primero que nada cambie `import faceapi from 'face-api.js';` por `import * as faceapi from 'face-api.js';` como me sugirió @porloscerrosΨ.

Aclaro que utilizo vue, e hice el import dentro de un componente en el script, algo así:

```
<template>
</template>
<script>
    import * as faceapi from 'face-api.js';
    export default {
        
    }
</script>
```

Esto debido a que una vez trabajé con vue-select y los estilos solo me funcionaron importando la librería dentro del complemento, y quería evitar problemas, pero no estoy seguro si se puede utilizar dentro de `resources/js/app.js` un `window.faceapi = require('face-api.js');`. Luego de hacer eso cada vez que compilaba me daba el siguiente error:

> WARNING in ./node_modules/face-api.js/build/es6/env/createFileSystem.js 5:17-30 Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\elias\Documents\PC_IV\Programacion_Computacional_IV\proyecto_final\node_modules\face-api.js\build\es6\env'

Para solucionarlo agregué la siguiente línea dentro de el archivo `webpack.mix.js`

```js
mix.webpackConfig({ resolve: { fallback: { fs: false } }});
```

Ahora el problema eran los módulos, pero eso es sencillo, dentro de la carpeta `storage/app/public` agrego una carpeta `modules` donde agrego todos los módulos, dentro de la carpeta `config/` se encuentra `filesystems.php`, asegurarse de que exista las siguientes líneas de código:

```php
'links' => [
    public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
],
```

Y si no existe ejecutar el siguiente comando dentro de consola (Yo uso windows, no estoy seguro si el comando puede cambiar según el SO):

```
>php artisan serve
```

Y al referenciar los modulos mediante `loadFromUri` se debe hacer así `('storage/modules')`.

Dejaré todo el código del componente por si les interesa:

`CameraComponent.vue`

```
<template>
    <div id="camera" class="border border-dark rounded-lg bg-slate-300 h-64 w-64 flex justify-center items-center">
        <video id="video" width="400" height="300" autoplay muted ref="video"></video>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import * as faceapi from 'face-api.js';
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
            }
        },
        methods: {
            startVideo() {
                const video = this.$refs.video;
                console.log(video, this.$refs.video);
                navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia;
                console.log(navigator.getUserMedia);
                if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
                    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
                        video: true
                    }).then(
                        stream => (video.srcObject = stream),
                        err => console.log(err)
                    );
                }
                video.addEventListener('play', function () {
                    const canvas = faceapi.createCanvasFromMedia(video);
                    document.body.append(canvas);
                    const displaySize = {
                        width: video.width,
                        height: video.height
                    };
                    faceapi.matchDimensions(canvas, displaySize);
                    setInterval(async () => {
                        const detections = await faceapi.detectAllFaces(video, new faceapi.TinyFaceDetectorOptions()).withFaceLandmarks().withFaceExpressions();
                        console.log(detections);
                        const resizedDetections = faceapi.resizeResults(detections, displaySize);
                        canvas.getContext('2d').clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                        faceapi.draw.drawDetections(canvas, resizedDetections);
                        faceapi.draw.drawFaceExpressions(canvas, resizedDetections);
                        faceapi.draw.drawFaceLandmarks(canvas, resizedDetections);
                    }, 100);
                });
            },
            loadModels() {
                Promise.all([
                    faceapi.nets.tinyFaceDetector.loadFromUri('/storage/models'),
                    faceapi.nets.faceLandmark68Net.loadFromUri('/storage/models'),
                    faceapi.nets.faceRecognitionNet.loadFromUri('/storage/models'),
                    faceapi.nets.faceExpressionNet.loadFromUri('/storage/models'),
                    faceapi.nets.ageGenderNet.loadFromUri('/storage/models'),
                ]).then(this.startVideo).catch(err => console.log(err));
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.loadModels();
        }
    }
</script>
```

`app.js`

```js
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue').default;

Vue.component('camera-component', require('./components/CameraComponent.vue').default);

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        
    },
});
```

`welcome.blade.php`

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Laravel - Face-Api</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/app.css')}}">
    </head>
    <body class="antialiased dark">
        <div id="app">
            <div class="bg-red-400 dark:bg-orange-400 w-full text-center text-white p-4 flex flex-wrap space-x-4">
                <h1 class="text-5xl">App Emotiva</h1>
                @include('partials.nav')
            </div>

            <camera-component></camera-component>
        </div>

        <script src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

[Modulos](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sb8u872wnvnr5i6/models.zip?dl=0)